# select()/FD_*() cause Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, select

I just like to test a bug about select listen more than 1024 files descriptor on Linux(Ubuntu 13.04/Debian 6).
And I override FD_SETSIZE and __FD_SETSIZE macros.

And then , perror() report have some errors while closing files descriptor at the end of program. On my PC like the following :(the quantity of errors depends on the quantity of listens).

```
closing file at 0
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 1
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 2
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 3
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 4
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 5
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 6
close: Bad file descriptor
closing file at 7
close: Bad file descriptor
```

the Code is following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define __FD_SETSIZE 8192
#define FD_SETSIZE 8192

#define NR_SELECT 2048 

char filename[10];

void init()
{
    struct rlimit* rlim;
    int n;
    rlim = (struct rlimit*)malloc(sizeof(struct rlimit));
    n=getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,rlim);
    if (n == -1) {
        perror("getrlimit");
        exit(1);
    }
    rlim->rlim_max=8192;
    rlim->rlim_cur=8192;

    n=setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,rlim);
    if (n == -1) {
        perror("setrlimit");
        exit(1);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    int fd[4096];
    int i;
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    init();

    /*clear and init a fd set*/
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);

    for (i=0;i<NR_SELECT;i++) {
        sprintf(filename,"./tst%d",i);
        fd[i]=open(filename,O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0666);
        if (fd[i] == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"opening at %dfile \n",i);
            perror("open while opening at \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<NR_SELECT;i++) {
        FD_SET(fd[i],&fdset);
        if (!FD_ISSET(fd[i],&fdset)) {
            fprintf(stderr,"checking fd[%d] in fdset",i);
            perror("FD_ISSET");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    tv.tv_sec=5;
    tv.tv_usec=0;

    retval = select(4096,&fdset,NULL,NULL,&tv);
    if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval) {
        printf("data available\n");
    }

    for (i=0;i<NR_SELECT;i++) {
        int n;
        n = close(fd[i]);
        if (n== -1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"closing file at %d\n",i);
            perror("close");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling will some warning about redefine Marcos.

Comment: Ugh, select. Have you considered using poll or epoll?

Comment: Try moving your #defines up to *before* your #include statements -- they can't affect the headers if they are parsed after the headers have already been pulled in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `FD_SETSIZE` before including whatever header that on your system happens to pull in `sys/select.h`. Otherwise that header will define it and your redefinition will either do nothing or break the FD_* macros.

Also. Don't use `select`. Use `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue` or any other modern interface that's designed to better deal with more than 20 file descriptors.

Comment: Thank you sir. But Now I'd like to verify select().